# PyVisa.errors.VisaIOError exception handling in Python

Tags: python-3.x, exception, pyvisa

I'm new to this...Can someone please tell me the appropriate way to do a `try: ... except: ...` in Python for the following:

```
File "C:\Python 3.6\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\highlevel.py", line 188, in _return_handler
    raise errors.VisaIOError(ret_value)
pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed.
```

I have tried `except pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError:`, `except VisaIOError:` and a few others, but the only thing I've found to work is `except:`.

Answer (score 2):

If all you `import` is `visa`, you can catch these exceptions with `except visa.VisaIOError`.

Example:

```
import visa

try:
    # Things that might raise VisaIOError here...
except visa.VisaIOError:
    # Handle the exception.
```

`visa.VisaIOError` is actually of type `<class 'pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError'>`, but directly imported by the top-level module named `visa` of the `pyvisa` package. You could thus also do `from pyvisa.errors import VisaIOError` or `from visa import VisaIOError` and then catch the exception with just `except VisaIOError`.